# Remove "{}" and " ' ' " from a printed item

Tags: python

When i print `item["Key"]`, i want to remove `{}` and `''` from that printed text:

```
print(f"The key for '{user}' was:", {item["Key"]})
```

Output:

```
The key for 'example' was: {'example-key'}
```

Comment: Remove the set creation using { and } and you should be good.

Comment: As @luk2302 said, what you are printing is a string that ends with `was:` and then a `set` with only one item (the `item["Key']`). Is it possible you wanted to do `f"The key for '{user}' was: {item['Key']}"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print without the braces `{}`

```
print(f"The key for '{user}' was:", item["Key"])
```

Comment: You can remove the comma. `f"The key for {user} was : {item['Key']}"`

Answer (score 1):

Using the *f-style* formatting for a *single* string object

```
print(f"The key for {user} was: {item['Key']}")
```

Notice that to access to the value of the dictionary the key should be passed with another symbol than the one used for initialize the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format()` for string formatting:

```
print("The key for {} was: {}".format(user, item["Key"]))
```

You can read more about string formatting here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use *c-style* formatting

```
print("The key for %s was: %s" % (user, item["Key"]))
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't explain the issue with the original code.